# Team Foundation Server 2010 Project Collection and Project Permissions

Tags: tfs, permissions

I'm new to Team Foundation Server 2010 and I have a question about permissions.

Is it possible for a project to inherit permissions from a project collection? I want to setup a custom contributor group at the project collection level and add the developers to it. Each time they create a new project I want to inherit the permissions from the project collection. That means I don't have to explicitly add the developers to the project each time they create one.

Maybe there is some other way of doing this and not having to setup a custom contributors group? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting up some Active Directory Groups along the lines of:

- TFS Contributors
- TFS Administrators
- TFS Project Managers

(You could also do this for specific projects. You get the idea.)

Give these AD groups the permissions you need, and simply add/remove the developers to the AD groups. If you can get the ability to manage the AD group, this will be much simpler that administering through the TFS admin tools.

Hopefully, you'll already have AD groups that fit these needs, saving you the trouble. Maybe a team-wide distribution list, for example?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Even if I went witht he AD groups (good idea) would I still have to explicitly add them to each project under the project collection?

Comment: I believe so - most configuration like this is done at the Team Project level. So, if you can structure your stuff all under the same Team Project, that might make it easier on you. Is there any reason you're using separate Team Projects (different process templates?)

Comment: I was going to create one team project for each application. It's strategy #1 from http://branchingguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Guidance%20for%20Structuring%20Team%20Projects&ProjectName=branchingguidance It's a common strategy that fits our department's goals.

Comment: The TFS Ranger's branching guidance is great.  That said, I disagree that the first strategy listed should be per-application.  Team Projects are fairly heavyweight and, especially with some custom configuration on Team Projects, the Team Project per-team strategy (#3) often makes the most sense in the real world.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Would you recommend still doing this with a small development shop (maybe 4-5 developers)?

Comment: If you have 5 developers, I would only have one team project.

Answer (score 1):

You can create collection level roles (TFS Groups) and edit your process template to grant permissions to those roles so there are set by default in every new project.